# Std::maps with template entries leads to unambiguous declaration

Tags: c++, stdmap, c++98

I am using C ++ 98. Am I allowed to declare a template as a type in a map?

I get the following error when I do so.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>

// below template declaration is in my header file

template <typename T> void function (T a, std::map<int, T> & val) // error 2782 Template parameter T is 
                                                               // unambiguous
{
    std::cout<< a;
    // some computations on the map
}

int main()
{

  std::map<int, std::vector<double>> mp_map;
  mp_map[0].push_back(1.0);
  mp_map[0].push_back(2.0);

 function(0.0, mp_map); 

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: change `std::map<double, std::vector<int,double>> mp_map` to `std::map<int, std::vector<double>> mp_map`

Comment: Is a `std::map<double, ...>` the same as a `std::map<int, ...>`?

Comment: The key in the map is fixed as an integer but the entries could be of ```T``` type.

Comment: @NathanOliver there was a typo, I have edited now

Comment: `template <typename T> void function (T a, std::map<int, T> & val)` is a template where the type of `a` should be the same as the value type of the map `val`. Is this the case for `function(0.0, mp_map); `?

Comment: please include the complete error message.  `T  is unambiguous` doesn't really make sense

Comment: `std::map<int, std::vector<double>>` is a syntax violation. Correct form is `std::map<int, std::vector<double> >`

Comment: don't confuse the template and its parameter. In your code `function` is the template. `T` is not a template, its the template parameter, ie there is no "template as type in the map"

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ah, I see

Comment: You declared `function(T, map<int,T>)`, which could be instantiated for `(double, map<int, double)`, but it can't match `(double, map<int, vector<double>>)` because `T` can only take one type in a given instantiation - it can't be both `double` and `vector<double>`

Comment: @eerorika yes, the new syntax is applicable from `c++11` standard

Comment: there is ambiguity, if it was unambiguous there would be no problem. please include the error message in the question

Comment: @idclev463035818  error C2782 Template parameter T is unambiguous. Thats how it reads

Comment: which compiler is this?

Comment: I wonder if this is a compiler bug / typo in the diagnostic message. Documentation says that C2782 means "'declaration' : template parameter 'identifier' is ambiguous" which is the opposite of what you quote.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it but here i read that `C2782` is "'declaration' : template parameter 'identifier' is ambiguous" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2782?view=msvc-160. "unambiguous" is the opposite and does not make sense in this context

Comment: better switch to a newer compiler then...